# Use two insert into statements in a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-insert

I tried to use two **insert into** statements in one stored procedure like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.test
  
AS
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #temp;

    SELECT *
    INTO #temp
    FROM sys.column_master_keys AS CMK;

    -- some statement
    -- some statement
    -- some statement

    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #temp;

    SELECT *
    INTO #temp
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS C;
END;
```

Error message :

> There is already an object named '#temp' in the database.

How to use one temporary table for many insert into in one stored procedure?

Comment: That isn't a temporal table, it's a **temporary** table; a temporal table is a very different type of table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is occurring because the code is *compiled* before it is run.  During the compilation phase, SQL Server sees the two `INSERT` statements that create the table.  It does not *execute* them, because it is only devising the execution plans.

Because the code is not being executed, the *compilation phase* misses the `DROP TABLE`.  Alas.  It sees that the table already exists when the second is executed, generating the error.

In any case, this is very easily fixed by giving the tables different names.

Answer (score 1):

You can use one temporary table for many insert into statements in one stored procedure.
To make it happen you have to use dynamic SQL.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.test
  
AS
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #temp;

    EXEC('SELECT *
    INTO #temp
    FROM sys.column_master_keys AS CMK;')

    -- some statement
    -- some statement
    -- some statement

    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #temp;

    EXEC('SELECT *
    INTO #temp
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS C;')
END;
```

Comment: Wow! that's great. in this solution we don't need **DROP TABLE** command, because command running in other batch.

Comment: @Amirhossein . . . This doesn't work if you actually want to *refer* to the temporary table (https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=dc4142ed62909604e4e2d7cd015030cc).  Stick with using different names.  It is the simplest solution.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Yes Gordon ,I changed it, I use this solution by a dynamic SP with out put and nested call SPs , in this SP can put any name and string and return out put of result. I need this solution for tSqlt framework. I need a  unique name for assert result of test in final log . It`s cleaner then change name for read logs for other developer in us team.  Thank you very much for your deep answers and support .

Comment: I'm amazed that you accepted an answer that demonstrably does not work in the sense of making the temporary table available after it has been created.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I made the wrong call. I mistakenly thought I was finding a great solution. But it was wrong. You are right this is not the true solution. This is not possible.

Comment: @GordonLinoff finally I create a table and use in SP